# Release Build of Xamarin Android App Fails, Debug Build Succeeds

Tags: android, xamarin, amazon-cognito

I have a Xamarin app that uses AWS Cognito.  It builds and runs fine when in Debug.  When I switch to Release I receive the following error:

Default Constructor not found for Type Amazon.Util.Internal.PlatformServices.NetworkReachability.

Steps I have taken to resolve:

1. Added INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.
2. Compared all build configuration screens for the project to insure Debug and Release match.
3. Turned off optimize code option.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I think you could try to use the [Custom Linker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker) or change the [Linking Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) in Project Options->Android Option->Linker properties to Sdk and User Assemblies

Comment: I changed the Linking options to "None" and it resolved the issue.  It seems that linking was stripping out some necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the Linking options to "None" resolved the issue.  It seems the linker was removing some necessary features.